# java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB002004: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST)

Tags: java

JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - JBWEB002004: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request (512) were detected. Any parameters beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.

How to resolve this issue. Without adding maxParameterCount in Standalone.xml. Any other solution for this to resolve this issues. Can anyone help me.

Comment: the need for so many parameters suggests the application is poorly designed in the first place. and this is a configuration issue and this exception is thrown by JBoss so you have to change its configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to solve "More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request" from application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139737/trying-to-solve-more-than-the-maximum-number-of-request-parameters-get-plus-po)